# Piecewise constant or 0-degree spline interpolation in Python/Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, piecewise, splines

Despite scipy's documentation indicating that [scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) will run on order k<=5, under the hood there is an additional constraint for order >=1. Does anyone know of a way to achieve either 0-degree spline or piecewise constant interpolation with Numpy/Scipy?

Comment: Isn't what you want here? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `interp1d` with `kind='zero'` or `kind='nearest'`.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried a simple trick
1) do numerical integration of step-wise constant function and you will get broken line
2) use 1. degree spline fit
3) calculate a derivative of the spline (method .derivative())

it has worked, but it could be better.