# How to interpolate over a piecewise-constant set of points with scipy or numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am having troubles in interpolating a set of piecewise-constant points.
To better explain, consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np  
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 30
Ts = 0.2

times = np.arange(0.0, N * Ts, Ts)
signal = np.concatenate((1.5 * np.ones(10), -0.5 * np.ones(10), np.ones(10)))
interp = UnivariateSpline(times[::3], signal[::3])

signal_interp = interp(times)

plt.plot(times, signal)
plt.plot(times, signal_interp)
plt.show()
```

I expected the plot of `signal_interp` to overlap the plot of `signal` but that is not happening.

I have found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084502/piecewise-constant-or-0-degree-spline-interpolation-in-python-scipy) but the [iterp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) is considered legacy.

I also tried to look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) but I could not find any guidance for my specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interp` is a function of times, not a function of signal.

You meant
`signal_interp = interp(times)`
not
`signal_interp = interp(signal)`

Which gives

[image]

It still doesn't "overlap" the initial signal. But splines cannot take the shape of piecewise-constant function. They are smooth by nature. It is what they do. They are used precisely for not being piecewise-constant. The reason why they appeared to be able to produce a piece-wise constant behavior with your initial code, is because what you were plotting were just 3 points of the spline, repeated 10 times each (since the abscissa used was `signal`, which contains only 3 values, repeated 10 times).

Nevertheless, you can still more, by reducing smooth factor `s`

```
interp = UnivariateSpline(times[::3], signal[::3], s=0.1)
plt.plot(times, signal)
plt.plot(times, interp(times))
```

[image]

### np interp

For a simple linear interpolation between each pair of consecutive point (so the less smooth possible),

```
signal_interp = np.interp(times, times[::3], signal[::3])
plt.plot(times, signal)
plt.plot(times, signal_interp)
```

[image]

Comment: Then, why not simply use `numpy.interp`?

Comment: make_interp_spline(x, y, k=1)